# Two Apache with Two Tomcat, Sticky session not working

Tags: mod-jk

We have environment with two Apache Web Server and Two Tomcat via Mod_jk. We have configured Both to Apache for Loadbalancer as well as failover.

We have a LB on top of both the Apache web Server configured in Round Robin Algorithm

Problem is randomly session gets invalidated when both the apache are running .

If One of the Apache is running loadbalancing and failover works perfectly fine.

Do i need to configure a two apache web server ?

Do i need to change some configuration for two apache for sticky session ?

Comment: Below are my two Apache configuration details

Comment: Can't see configuration details. Why is your entire question code formatted?